# symbol from libc++ is searched for in the wrong library at runtime

Tags: c++, macos, dynamic-linking

I have an application which links to our own library and boost date_time, both using libc++ (with clang).

When running the application it stops right away looking for __ZTISt12out_of_range ( = "typeinfo for std::out_of_range") in the boost library.

```
bash-3.2$ ./communicator 
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTISt12out_of_range
  Referenced from: (...)/../Frameworks/libsipclient.dylib
  Expected in: (...)/../Frameworks/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib
 in (...)/../Frameworks/libsipclient.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

They both have it as undefined symbol, and /usr/libc++.1.dylib has it:

```
bash-3.2$ nm -u ../Frameworks/{libsipclient,libboost_date_time-mt}.dylib | grep __ZTISt12out_of_range
__ZTISt12out_of_range
__ZTISt12out_of_range
bash-3.2$ nm /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib | grep __ZTISt12out_of_range
000000000006d5c0 S __ZTISt12out_of_range
```

Both uses libc++ with correct path according to otool:

```
bash-3.2$ otool -L ../Frameworks/libsipclient.dylib | grep -e libboost -e libc
        @executable_path/../Frameworks/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 65.1.0)
bash-3.2$ otool -L ../Frameworks/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib 
../Frameworks/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib:
        @executable_path/../Frameworks/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 65.1.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

libsipclient.dylib was linked originally to a boost::date_time which was linked to libstdc++ instead of libc++ (linker arguments had that path earlier than the libc++ one).